# SharePoint central admin deleted from IIS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Can someone please help me.
Someone deleted SharePoint 2013 central admin from IIS from one server. However, I can still see central admin database is available. Moreover, `wssroot-wss-virtualdirectories`is also available under C drive. The only things missing is from IIS. due to which we are getting error `page can`t be displayed`.

DO any one know the procedure to make this work.

Comment: have you tried to run Microsoft SharePoint configuration wizard ?

Comment: Nope not yet. I think it will bring down all other sites right? Moreover will it use existing database while creating new central admin or it will create brand new central admin?

Answer (score 1):

Go into powershell on one of your SharePoint 2013 servers and use `Get-SPServiceInstance` in order to get the Central Administration and Web Application service instances on the box you are targeting.

Then once you have the two GUIDs for those two instances - use the following for both the web application and central administration services.

```
Stop-SPServiceInstance <GUID>
Start-SPServiceInstance <GUID>
```

This will essentially recreate the web application in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. I ran get-spserviceinstance, however, I see several services as output but unable to find central administration as well as web application services. any comment please

Comment: try `Get-SPServiceInstance | select TypeName, Status, Id, Server | out-gridview` and it should be typename, `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application` and `Central Administration` make sure the `ID` correlates with the `Server` you are trying to stop/start

Comment: thanks. Now I am able to run the powershell and I can see central admin in IIS and it is online. However, when I browse central admin, it is authenticating for credentials always even after entering farm admin credentials. Do I need to complete any other step?

Answer (score 1):

**Run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on that server.**

- Press "Next"
- Make sure the right database server and database is selected
- Make sure "Do not disconnect from this server farm" is selected
- Press "Next"
- Press "Advanced settings"
- Make sure to select "Use this machine to host the web site" in "Host Central Administration Web Application" window
- Press "Ok"
- Press "Next"
- Wait for configuration to finish

**Then Central Administration is installed properly on this machine.**

Comment: Thanks Phil, will bring any sites down? or there won't be any outage while running this?

Comment: Very good explanation of Phil. This won't delete any of your sites. But it will interrupt availability of your farm, as all services will get stopped while Products Configuration Wizards does it's work.

Comment: If Phils solution does not work, first select "Yes, i want to remove the web site from this machine" (means: CentralAdmin only). This will remove the broken components of your CentralAdmin. Then follow Phils steps again to redeploy CentralAdmin.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will do this during after hours and give you an update.   I have two app servers which runs central admin and seems to be issue from both the servers now.